# Override the setValue in zend form

Tags: php, oop, zend-form

I want the zend form to override the setValue function so that the value given to the function can be manipulated. How can i implement this?

My current form structure is like this:

```
class  My_Form_Login   
{   
 public $Form;  
 public $Username;      
 public function  __construct()  
    {  
        $this->Form = new Form_Abstract();  
        $this->init();  
    }  
 public function init()  
    {  
     $this->Username ->setValue('100');  
    }  
}    

class Form_Abstract extends Zend_Form  
{  
    public function __construct($options = null)  
    {  
        parent::__construct($options);  
        $this->setDecorators(array(  'FormElements','FormErrors','Form' ));  
    }  

    public function setValue($value)
    {     
        $strippedValue = stripslashes($value);  
        return parent::setValue($strippedValue);  
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Zend_Form into your own class like:

```
My_Form extends Zend_Form
{
  public function setValue($arg)
  {
    // My override code here
  }
}
```

Then use this class instead of the Zend_Form directly

Comment: You would need to use: `$form = new My_Form` instead of `$form = new Zend_Form` in order to utilize your `setValue()` function

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Zend filter interface instead. For example

```
class My_Filter_Stripslashes implements Zend_Filter_Interface
{
    public function filter($value)
    {
        return get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? $this->_clean($value) : $value;
    }

    protected function _clean($value)
    {
        return is_array($value) ? array_map(array($this, '_clean'), $value) : stripslashes($value);
    }
}
```

Then apply this to your elements after adding them

```
$form->setElementFilters(array(new My_Filter_Stripslashes));
```